# Display left value only once

Tags: database, join, distinct

I've got two tables (customer, purchase).  I've joined these two tables via the customerid key.  This works great.  My table looks like:

```
Cust_Name | Purchase $
Mike          2.00
Mike          3.00
Mike          4.00
Mike         10.00
Mike         30.00
```

But what I would  like to display is the `Cust_name` only once (left table) and keep the display of `Purchase $` the same.  So it would look like:

```
Cust_Name | Purchase $
Mike          2.00
              3.00
              4.00
             10.00
             30.00
```

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this easily (I loathe to say at all) with a pure SQL `SELECT` query. You could run a `CURSOR` over the table if you create it as a temp table first but  but IMO this is a task better suited for your business or presentation layers.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something you should do in a `SQL` query.

In a relational database, having a dollar amount on the right without a corresponding value on the left to tie it to is essentially meaningless.

Any aesthetic changes like this should be handled in your **application or presentation layer**, not in the logic of the database.